# JWT based Authentication/Authorization Vs Microsoft Identity 2

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, jwt

I have a AngularJS/Web API/SQL Server application that currently uses token based authentication and authorization using the article outlined below:

[JSON Web Token in ASP.NET Web API 2 using Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)

There has been a request to change this security mechanism to use Microsoft Identity. My initial research appears to suggest that JWT has more advantages as it can facilitate accessing multiple resource servers (single sign on scenario) and has a nice way of decoupling the different layers.

On the other hand, Identity is coupled with Entity framework (I use Dapper and do understand that I can write a custom provider) and it appears to be difficult to implement if your Web API is shared across multiple consumers (Web and Mobile app). But Microsoft recommends this framework for Authentication/Authorization. I ran into this [article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) that helps implement it with AngularJS/Web API. Can someone help me understand if one is more favorable than the other and how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft identity is not binded to entity framework you can write custom identity classes to use nhibernate & other O/R mappers